# Error when inserting in to MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users' (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES ('ri' at line 1

```
INSERT INTO 'users' (`username`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES ('rikars', '5aa9d6460f4ada3eb6611d6fda437317', 'Arsen', 'Babajanyan', 'rikarsenbabajanyan@gmail.com')
```

Comment: why downvote? it's a mistake in the code, like almost all the questions in SoF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table name cannot be in quotes. You can and should use ticks, however:

```
INSERT INTO `users`
            (`username`, 
             `password`, 
             `first_name`, 
             `last_name`, 
             `email`) 
VALUES      ('rikars', 
             '5aa9d6460f4ada3eb6611d6fda437317', 
             'Arsen', 
             'Babajanyan', 
             'rikarsenbabajanyan@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Trying to make it a habit when I answer low quality questions